# c# Cefsharp. Проблема с vue.js

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Столкнулся с проблемой CefSharp с использованием vue.js на сайте. Проблема в том что нужно нажимать по меню раза два чтобы перешел на нужный url, так же список и кнопки нужно кликать по три раза чтобы сработало. В обычных браузерах работает всё как нужно. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: vue.js - понятие растяжимое и к работе ссылок отношение не имеющее. Покажите HTML примеры рабочей и не рабочей ссылки.

Comment: @aepot, я понял что ошибка не в vue.js а то что сайт использует vuetify.js

Comment: инспектируйте HTML, смотрите, какие обработчики события на клике висят, какая функция вызывается если нажать на ссылку, если дело не в событиях, то смотрите слои визуала, есть ли надо ссылкой другие HTML элементы, которые потенциально могут помешать на нее нажать.